# javascript - object property visible across the inheritance chain

Tags: javascript, oop, constructor, new-operator

Here is an interesting thing I found but don't know why it happens.

I create

```
var Person = new Object;

var billy = Person;
var emily = Person;
```

then I assign a name property to emily

```
 emily.name = "emily"
```

When I check hasOwnProperty(name) on billy and Person I get, true. When I check billy.name and Person.name, I get "emily".

Why does giving emily a name, set everyone with a name property and assign it the same value?

Comment: because you just create one object and three pointers to it (the same).

Comment: There is no 'inheritance' here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Person` is an object

```
var Person = {}
```

You give `billy` and `emily` a copy of the object's address owned by `Person`

```
var billy = Person;
```

> `Billy`, you watch those properties at this place in memory.

```
var emily = Person;
```

> `Emily`, you watch those properties at this place in memory.

At this part, both watch the same object at the same place in memory.
When this object change (access by `Person`, `billy` or `emily`) then all see the same modified object.

```
var Person = address Ox27382738
var bily = address(Person)
var emily = address(Person)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you have one object and are creating different references to that Object.

```
var Person = new Object;
```

This line creates a new object and assigns Person the reference to that Object.

```
var billy = Person;
var emily = Person;
```

The above two lines are just creating new references billy and emily to the Object created before. So, all three references(Person, Billy, Emily) are pointing to the same object.

If you access or change any field using any of references the result will be the same because all the references are pointing to the same Object.

In this case

```
emily.name == billy.name == Person.name
```